# how to handle two elements in css

Tags: css, syntax, positioning

How do you call it in css when you have a syntax like this:

```
background-image: url(../images/image1.png), url(../images/logo_pagina_image2.png);
background-position: top left, top right;
```

that is, when you address two elements at the same time on the same rows?

because I actually want image1.png to have an absolute position, and I want it to have left:-20px, but I'm not familiar with the kind of syntax so I don't know how to write it

Comment: multiple background images?

Answer (score 1):

**This is called to Multiple Background Images**

Multiple background images can be specified using either the individual background properties or the background shorthand property.

**Example:**

```
background-image: url(../images/image1.png), url(../images/logo_pagina_image2.png);
background-position: 0 -20px, top right;
background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

**[More About this](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)**

**[Demo here is define three image in background](http://jsfiddle.net/xa0cndco/)**

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for multiple background images. Here is an example of usage:

```
background: 
url(../images/image1.png) -20px 0 no-repeat,                 /* On top */
url(../images/logo_pagina_image2.png) right top no-repeat;   /* beneath image1.png */
```

You can also specify the backgrounds like this (i.e. split up the image and position declarations):

```
background-image: url(../images/image1.png), url(../images/logo_pagina_image2.png);
background-position: -20px 0, right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

background-image: url(../images/image1.png) -20px 0 norepeat , url(../images/logo_pagina_image2.png) 0 0;